# Locate specific text in Google Sheets using the API

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-php-client

I have a Google Sheet and I am able to extract the ID of the file using Google Drive API. I'd like to search the file for specific text using the API, specifically I want to extract the row and column of the text. I found information on [developer metadata](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.developerMetadata/search) on the docs, but there is no php example and I am lost.

Comment: I would use the `spreadsheets.values` method to retrieve the sheet values in an array of `<dimension>` arrays. Then you can determine the array indices using appropriate filter expressions. If you only need to locate the usage to replace the text, use the dedicated find-replace API call.

Comment: @tehhowch, can you write an answer with a demo code and i will mark it as an accepted answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to convert the file to plain text using this code:

```
$response = $service->files->export($fileId, 'text/csv', array(
'alt' => 'media'));
```

and using this code to get the full content of the file

```
$content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
```

and then with a simple regex i was able to extract all the data i needed. Maybe this is not the best solution, but it is good workaround for me. This is my regex in case anyone is wondering

```
$re = '/"(.*?) at (.*?)",(.*?' . $order['Phone'] . '),.*?,([0-9]+)/m';
preg_match_all($re, $content, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
```